# clojure how to get the index of an item in a 2d list

Tags: list, clojure, indexing

If I have a list like...

```
(def test [[1 2 3]
           [4 5 6]
           [7 8 9]])
```

and I want the index of 5 (which would be (1,1)) how would I do that?
so (find 5 test) = (1,1)

Answer (score 10):

Using list comprehension (for) the the list of all matching positions can be found:

```
(def test [[1 2 3][4 5 6][7 8 9]])

(for [[x row] (map-indexed vector test) 
      [y val] (map-indexed vector row) 
      :when (= 5 val)]
   [x y])
 => ([1 1])
```

EDIT:  Using destructuring works for the 'for' function.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a builtin function for that operation, but it shouldn't be hard to write one.

You could flatten the nested vectors, into a single list, then search, take the resulting index and split out the x and y coordinates, using the length of the first nested vector.

```
(defn find2d [data item]
  (let [n (count (first data))
        i (.indexOf (flatten data) item)]
    (if (pos? i)
      (list (quot i n) (mod i n)))))

(find2d data 5) ;=> (1 1)
```

Comment: Nice, I like your solution better. I always forget about the java methods associated with seqs.

Comment: nice!. but as the other answer suggested am i looking at this the wrong way? if u want to do A* search on a eight puzzle?

Comment: I don't have a strong grasp of the algorithms involved, but I don't think you need to nest the vectors like that. You could use a flat vector to start with, and a row length.

Comment: hmmm kk thnx for the help. i was originally using this to calculate the number of moves it take to get from one tile slot to another. i guess i should find another way

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want:

```
(defn indexof-2D [item mat]
  (letfn [(index-of-row 
           [x]
           (first (keep-indexed #(if (= item %2) %1) x)))]
    (->> mat
         (map-indexed #(vector %1 (index-of-row %2)))
         (filter last)
         first)))
```

Now I don't know what your use case is, but generally using indexes to solve a problem in clojure is a sign that you are probably approaching the problem from the wrong angle. The above function shouldn't be used in high performance matrix calculations, but is sufficiently performant until deemed otherwise.

Comment: I am new to clojure. I am trying to use this to help me with A* search on a eight puzzle

Answer (score 0):

I agree with mortalapeman that you might be approaching the problem in wrong angle. I dont know much about A* search on eight puzzle so I will not attempt to solve that.

But I would approach finding the index of a 2d list as below:

```
(defn indexof [y xs]
  (last (find (clojure.set/map-invert (map-indexed vector xs)) y)))

(let [i (indexof 5 (flatten test))] 
  [(int (/ i 3)) (mod i 3)])
```

I defined a function indexof to find the index of an element in the given sequence. The function will first create a vector of index and value. The result is then inverted so that you have a map of value to index. Please note that this function works only if you have unique elements in your list. I assuming the numbers are unique in your problem (correct me if I am wrong).

The later clojure statement will flatten the list and find the index of the given element and convert the index to the 2d index.

Answer (score 0):

As a generalized solution, assuming that you eventually want the indices of all elements of  your nested sequences, you could create a map of all the elements to their indices with this:

```
(defn mat->map
  [mat]
  (into {} (for [[i row] (map-indexed vector mat)
                 [j key] (map-indexed vector row)]
             [key [i j]])))
```

Comment: For a 3x3 matrix as in the OP this works well.  However it won't scale if the `mat` is a large or infinite seq.

Comment: @MSmith: Yes, of course. This is an efficient solution if you need the indices of many elements of a small matrix, but not so much if you need just a few elements of a large matrix.